# How do I close a single tab in a Chrome browser?

Tags: vb.net

I am starting a PDF. It is being opened in a Chrome tab.

According to [Jimis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73008002/why-is-the-process-id-not-found-in-getprocesses) in my other question, the following happens:

```
The Process object that opened the PDF doesn't exist anymore after the main Chrome Process presents the PDF content in a tabbed Window. Find the Chrome Process and check the current title of its Window.
```

Now I want to close this PDF again.
I go through all windows to find the name of the PDF.

I find it by using the PDF's name and adding " - Google Chrome".

The following window is found:

```
"test.pdf - Google Chrome"
```

However, when I close this window, the entire browser window is closed, not only the one tab.

Does anybody know why and how to avoid that?

Comment: You may see if [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) meets your needs. To open a pdf: `webView21.Source = new Uri("file:///C:/Temp/test.pdf", UriKind.Absolute);` - where `webView21` is an instance of WebView2.

Comment: @user9938 Thanks, but I don't have access to the browser... it opens automatically when I open a PDF. You mean I should just switch to another browser like Edge or so, right?

Comment: No, the suggestion is to add a [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) Control (Edge Chrome based, replaces the old WebBrowser Control, IE 7/11 based), so you can show the PDF inside your own application -- If you have the PDF bytes - because you're, e.g., generating the PDF yourself - you could also show it directly, without saving to file, with something like this: [Set Webview2 Source directly to a binary stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68671066/7444103). Otherwise, just open the PDF file in WebView2 as described. No plug-ins required.

Comment: Ah, ok, yes, sure, I was just wondering how I could solve this situation. I don't want to give up.

Comment: The simple way? Send `CTRL + F4` to the Chrome app. It will close the active tab.

Comment: Hmmm. :-) This is not really what I mean... :-)